# How can I add non-breaking space (&nbsp;) in dates using search and replace in DreamWeaver

Tags: find-and-replace, dreamweaver

### Example:

```
January 1, 2012
```

This is the current text, but I want to change the source code to:

```
January&nbsp;1&nbsp;2012
```

automatically using search and replace.

There are multiple dates in the document so I am looking for a quick and easy snippet to do this in one shot throughout the document.

Comment: Do all the dates have consistent format, such as `<monthname> <day of month>, <4-digit year>`?